# Getting Started Tutorial for the ASA 2.9.0 package

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I am using Unity 2020.3 with the XR-Plugin and therefore use the ASA 2.9.0 package. Is there a "getting started tutorial" for this? Where can I find proper instruction on how to use it? I know it exists for the ASA 2.7.0, but the packages for that SDK are not compatible with ASA 2.9.0.

Answer (score 8):

The ["Getting started with ASA" tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-asa-02) which uses the Mixed Reality Toolkit (MRTK) does only target ASA SDK 2.7 as of April 2021.

For just Unity + ASA, there are quickstart tutorials in [the ASA Unity overview documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/unity-overview), which explain how to use the ASA 2.9.

Comment: Thanks. I already worked with the ASA 2.9 samples from the documentation page. It would be really amazing to have something similar to the "Getting started with ASA" tutorial for the ASA 2.9 in the future (integrating MRTK). It's very straight forward.